# Chrome extension: XMLHttpRequest for dynamically populated content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an extension which searches for ratings of movies on Douban. Please note that this question would involve some texts in Chinese. However, I will translate the them where necessary.

---

Here's a brief description of how this extension should work:

1. Mouse cursor hovers over a movie on Netflix
2. Get the movie information (such as title and year of publication)
3. Opens a XMLHttpRequest and search on a Chinese movie rating website https://movie.douban.com. The `GET` url would be: `'https://movie.douban.com/subject_search?cat=1002&search_text=' + search text`
4. Locate the movie and get its detail page, such as https://movie.douban.com/subject/26992364/.
5. Get the rating from the detail page.

---

The problem is, the search page of the website is 'dynamically loaded' (not sure if this is the correct term).

For example, if I search for 'seal team', once the page is fully loaded, the search results can be found in the `<div id="wrapper"> </div>` block.:

[image]

---

Now, if I try to get the html using `XMLHttpRequest`, I cannot get any search results in the "wrapper" block, and it shows 正在搜索...(*translate:* Searching...) instead:

[image]

---

The manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "TestExt",
  "version": "0.1",

  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "TestExt"
  },

  "permissions": ["activeTab",
    "https://movie.douban.com/subject_search?cat=1002&search_text=*"]
}
```

The background.js code:

```
function test() {
    var xHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xHttp.open("GET", "https://movie.douban.com/subject_search?cat=1002&search_text=seal", false);
    xHttp.send();
    console.log("request sent!")
    if (xHttp.readyState == 4 && xHttp.status == 200) {
      var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xHttp.responseText, "text/html");
      console.log(doc)
    }
  }

  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    test();
});
```

---

Sorry, but I failed to find an English website with the similar behaviour. If you know one and would let me know, I shall update the post.

Comment: The usual approach is to reverse-engineer the site's method of getting this data. Open devtools on that site URL and see if it makes some API requests so you can use it directly. Or maybe there's a JSON object in the page HTML. Or you can load the URL in a hidden iframe in the background page, have a content script run within it automatically which will post the results back to extension when it detects them by using periodic checks (setInterval) or MutationObserver.

Comment: @wOxxOm The website does have an api; sadly it is not open to individual developers. I have checked the websit's network requests. The search result is not acquired through xhr. I will study the hidden iframe. thanks